# How can I eliminate the 'main' routine of the flex & bison so I can put the lexing and parsing process into a library?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm working on a parser that parses json string and I want to make it a library.
The problem is that when I use ld to link the library I wrote, 
there's a error message:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
json-parser.o:/build/buildd/flex-2.5.35/libmain.c:29: first defined here
```

how can I fix this..? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

using `gcc -o charcount  charcount.o -lfl` instead of  `gcc -o charcount -lfl charcount.o` may be help.

It's strange that the order of object file and shared library make crucial sense here, but the reversion really works.

Comment: It's not strange, it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682741/1983495).

Answer (score 6):

Since neither flex nor bison creates the main function for you, it must be your own `main()` in the code that is getting in the way of the library.  Basically, do not put `main()` into a library.

However, it is only fair to note that both the Flex library (`-lfl`, `/usr/lib/libfl.*`) and the Yacc library (`-ly`, `/usr/lib/liby.*`) do in fact contain a rudimentary `main()` program.  If you use either or both of those libraries, then, you must make sure your own object file with `main()` is linked before the libraries are scanned.